# how to get only two number after decimal

Tags: sql-server

i have money field in sql table when i m extracting record by table and binding it to datagrid it show money as well 100.0000 four character from decimal i need only two .
Plz suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    ROUND(YourColumn,2)
    FROM ...
```

Test it out:

```
DECLARE @YourTable table (RowValue money)
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (123.4321)
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (0.001)
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (1.1251)

SELECT  
    RowValue, ROUND(RowValue,2) AS TwoPlaces
    FROM @YourTable
```

OUTPUT:

```
RowValue              TwoPlaces
--------------------- ---------------------
123.4321              123.43
0.001                 0.00
1.1251                1.13

(3 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion this formatting should be done on the UI side.

The below example shown uses an ASP.NET DataGrid.  Within the column you need to specify the **DataFormatString** property on the column.  The **{0:C2}** in this case displays the property as a currency with 2 decimal places

---

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="grid1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Product Name" DataField="Name" />
        <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Price" DataField="Price" DataFormatString="{0:C2}" />
    </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select cast(round(123.4321,2) as decimal(18,2))
```

is also a solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning the data in numeric format, and you should (as opposed to converting it to a string), then this is an application presentation/formatting issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [GridView Examples for ASP.NET 2.0: Formatting the GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx).

You need to set the [DataFormatString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx) property to eg. *"{0:0.00}"*